# How to call function/method in code behind file from .js file?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, code-behind

I have a Ajax method which check some condition, if the condition fails, then i'm showing a message through alert box. But i need to call function on the aspx page to do some other part.

**My Sample Code:**

```
function myWebService(param1, param2, param3) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebServices/WebServiceMethod",
        data: JSON.stringify({ param1: param1, param2: param2, param3: param3 }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d) {
                var obj = function callbackfunction() {
                    myWebService(param1, param2, param3);
                }

                window.setTimeout(obj, 10000);
            }
        else {
                    alert("WebMethod checked the condition and it was failed.");
                  // I need to call method in code behind file from here. 
                }
            }
        }

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to implement through another WebMethod and Ajax Call, but the problem is i'm calling above myWebService method from 5 different pages and i need to call code-behind function for all the pages
in else block.(all aspx pages has the function with SAME name, but the inside code is differs from each page). I don't know how to set-up URL in this case.

is there any preferable way to call method in code-behind file from the above function ???

Comment: I think your problem is just to generate dynamic URL and then make a call.

Comment: you can use __doPostBack();

Comment: Somehow i need to generate dynamic URL. Can you assist me how to do? @Reddy

Comment: @Knowledge2Share you can maintain a config variable like key value of your  axpx page and the method to call. Then when ever you want to make a call just retrieve the URL and see which page you are currently in then extract the corresponding method name and call it. Let me know if you want a code snippet for this

Comment: Yes please.. really helpful...! @Reddy

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Web.Services.WebMethod` to allow jQuery to call server side ASP.NET methods (without the use of PostBack). This [article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) has a good step-through guide.


Basically you need to add an attribute to your static code-behind method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static String MyMethod()
{
    return "My Method from code-behind"
}
```

And in you javascript:

```
function myWebService(param1, param2, param3) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod", // will make AJAX call to your code-behind code
        // rest of you code...
    });
}
```

Comment: But my URL will be different for each page. I need to call same method(inside code might be different) which is present on 5-6 pages through web service or some other way